# What is the proper way to specify that my python package depends on opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, packaging, setup.py, python-packaging

Say I'm making a python package that depends on OpenCV library. The problem is OpenCV library for python is not present on PYPI, so the question is how do I specify this dependency (and dependencies like that) in my `setup.py` file? I am aware of `opencv-python`, but I want the package to play well with the `opencv` from conda so I wonder if it will cause conflicts.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/ ?

Comment: @rdas it's not an official distribution

Comment: In general, the answer would be a PEP508 Environment Marker to mark `opencv-python` for non-Conda installations only, but unfortunately Conda doesn't set a marker for itself...

Comment: @AKX can you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: @monomonedula just to keep it up-to-date: it is official distribution now.